# Vue - perform an action on just the newly added element in a v-for array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a v-for array that holds a bunch of elements. After the user performing certain actions, I insert another element at the front of the array.

I want the element to initially have a height of 0, and to slowly expand to a height of 150px. The other elements should remain 150px like they were before.

My failed attempt was to try to assign a class with height 0 to the the newly inserted element:

```
    <div id="brickHolder">
      <svg
        v-for="brick in bricks" :id="brick.id"
        class="expandable" :class="{not_expanded: keepShut(brick.id)}"
      </svg>
    </div>
```

```
    keepShut(id) {
      return id === this.bricks[0].id
    },
```

And to then remove it, triggering the expansion animation:

```
        let parent = document.getElementById("brickHolder");
        parent.children[0].classList.remove('not_expanded');
```

But that doesn't work. What's a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. But [List Transitions](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-list.html) might be a solution.

Comment: @tauzN woah thank you for this! that's exactly what I needed! feel free to post an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution would be to use [List Transitions](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-list.html) i Vue.